# I want to create a program that reads text file

Tags: python

it does work if I type this on python shell

```
>>> f= open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test1.txt'), 'r')
>>> f.read()
'plpw eeeeplpw eeeeplpw eeee'
>>> f.close()
```

but if I create a python program, i doesn't work.

```
import os
f= open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test1.txt'), 'r')
f.read()
f.close()
```

i saved this piece of code by using text editor.
if I execute this program in python shell, it shows nothing.
please tell me why..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interactive prompt, it automatically prints anything a function call returns. That means the return value of `f.read()` is printed automatically. This won't happen when you put it in a program however, so you will have to `print` it yourself to have it show up.

```
import os
f = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test1.txt'), 'r')
print f.read()  # use print(f.read()) in Python 3
f.close()
```

Another suggestion I would make would be to use a [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) block:

```
import os
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test1.txt'), 'r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

This means that you won't have to worry about manually closing the file afterwards.

Comment: FYI, you can use the function equivalent of `print` in Python 2.6+ by adding `from __future__ import print_function` at the very top.